# software removal in Ubuntu

Tags: software-uninstall

hey I'm new user of Ubuntu and i want to remove the app called "additional driver" from Ubuntu 20.04. I don't have any graphics card in my laptop so please tell me how to remove this app.

And is it safe to remove "additional driver" app.pls tell me effects that I'll face after uninstalling the app.

Comment: You can't .. and why bother ? It is a Tab in "Software & Updates", you don't have to go there.

Comment: Its not safe and you shouldn't care about intrinsic apps. If you think that Ubuntu is bloated, you could build your own system with [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/).

Comment: Even if you did install it; you may gain no additional free disk space.  Most applications use shared libraries, that is actually a function of a larger program which you likely should not remove (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu ; not it's a function of the GUI tool, not an app in itself).  You risk making the rest of the functionality abort & not load, not run or being unreliable. If you use a server install, it is not installed.

Comment: " I don't have any graphics card in my laptop" Yes you do. Otherwise the display does not show you anything.You have at least a discrete graphicscard from Intel.

Answer (score 1):

The Additional Drivers tab of the software & Updates window is launched by running the  `software-properties-gtk` command in the terminal. The software-properties-gtk package provides an abstraction of the used apt repositories. It allows you to easily manage your distribution and independent software vendor software sources. As you can see in the below screenshot uninstalling the software-properties-gtk package would remove some other built-in functionality from Ubuntu and it is a dependency of the ubuntu-desktop-minimal package among others, so there's no good reason to remove it.

[image]

In general it's not a good idea to randomly delete packages without checking first with `apt-cache rdepends package-name`if they are required by other packages that are installed.